# VBA in Excel: Getting error using a range

Tags: vba, excel, range

I've been extensively searching for the answer to this, but no one seems to have an answer for me.

What I want my code to do is simple - I want to remove the background color from a section of cells that the user chooses. This would be triggered when the user presses a button.

My code is:

```html
Private Sub clrhi_Click()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select a range from which you wish to remove the highlight", "Select a Range", Type:=8)
    Range(rng.Address).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
End Sub
```

When I run it, it hits an error (Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error) on the last line right above End Sub.

I've also tried:

```html
Private Sub clrhi_Click()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select a range from which you wish to remove the highlight", "Select a Range", Type:=8)
    rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
End Sub
```

and get the same error in the same place.

The last bit I tried was:

```html
Private Sub clrhi_Click()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select a range from which you wish to remove the highlight", "Select a Range", Type:=8)
    Range(rng).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
End Sub
```

and I get a different error (Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed).

Can anyone help me out on this one? Much appreciated.

Comment: It works fine for me (your first code at least, the only one I tried). Could you give us some more information (for example how to configure our spreadsheet in order to replicate the error)?

Comment: Try qualifying the Range(rng.Address).Interior.ColorIndex = 0 statement with its parent worksheet.

Comment: Your second code example is the correct way to use range. The error would appear to be caused by  `rng` being nothing when the error line is reached. Put a breakpoint on the line and check the value in `rng`.

Comment: The second code should work if you can change the background of the same range manually - if the sheet is protected, you will get error 1004

Comment: user3964075 - you solved my problem, I forgot that the sheet had been protected by an earlier macro. I can't believe I overlooked something as simple as that! My confidence as a programmer has been restored.

Thanks to everyone else for their suggestions :)